# Switch OnRebuildIndex using Azure Search

Tags: azure-search

I'm using Azure search in Sitecore 8.2 update 1 version, looking for configuration to set switch on rebuild index. Every time when we do rebuilding indexes, we are seeing downtime with empty results.

I have seen switch on rebuild indexes for Lucene/Solr but not for azure search in the Sitecore documentation.
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/configure_azure_search

Anyone tried on Azure search configuration to set switchonRebuild Index, Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Azure Search does not yet support (or simulate) this functionality.

Best you could do is to reconfigure your CM and build a new index name out, then update the configs on the CDs. Will likely need an AppPool recycle unless you do something tricky, so I hope you have load balancers.

It's a bit ugly at the moment, but getting better...

Comment: Yes Richard, I'm using Azure web app instances which have load balancing config. I have a new custom index as normal stuff. Looking forward some support from Sitecore as well on this.

Comment: @SivaSankar please mark as answer if you found this helpful so that it does not appear on the "unanswered" list forever.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

This is now supported in Sitecore versions 8.2.7 and 9.0.2 and later.

From the link below:

> A full index rebuild executes in a separate rebuild index. When the
>   rebuild operation finishes, Sitecore switches the Search service to
>   use the new rebuilt index as the primary search index. After this,
>   Sitecore deletes the previous Search index.

You can control the Switch On Rebuild feature with the following index configuration settings:

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Azure.SwitchOnRebuild" value="true"/>
```

To avoid downtime of the Search functionality during an index rebuild, use this setting to specify whether the Azure Search provider uses the SwitchOnRebuild functionality. The default value is true.

```
<setting name="ContentSearch.Azure.SwitchOnRebuildCleanUpDelay" value="00:01:00"/>
```

You can set a time buffer to prevent Sitecore deleting the old index before all of the roles have been switched over to work with the newly rebuilt index. The default value is 00:01:00 (1 minute). You can only use this when the SwitchOnRebuild feature is enabled.

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/zero-downtime-index-rebuild-in-azure-search.html